# If mp.isPlaying() causes app to crush

Tags: android, media-player

I am using a MediaPlayer. Somewhere inside my code I use:

```
if (mp != null) {
    System.out.println("This");
    if (mp.isPlaying()) //1
        System.out.println("That"); //2
}
```

And as I run it, the app for some reason stops from working. If I delete the //1 and //2 lines, is runs normally and it prints "This". But why, I just want to check if mp is playing or not

Comment: it's huge man, I just seperated the specific code it causes to crush

Comment: where do you initialize the mediaplayer?

Comment: post the crash dude... stack trace... something...

Comment: I initialize it inside an onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp). It doesn't inform me where the error is, logcat and eventlog are clear

Comment: you cant initialise it in onCompletion... onCompletion means that it was already initialised and that it played the source file till the end...

Answer (score 1):

as you can see on Android [MediaPlayer documentations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying())

> public boolean isPlaying ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Checks whether the MediaPlayer is playing.
>
> Returns true if currently playing, false otherwise ***Throws
>   IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been
>   initialized or has been released***.

check if you are initialising the MediaPlayer correctly and that you haven't released it before calling isPlaying().

please mark it as correct answer if that helped you.